# Adobe AIR on Mac - Access Bluetooth data

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, bluetooth, air

I am exploring some ideas and trying to make three different applications talking each other via bluetooth.
Two of them would run on Android phones, while the third would run on a MacMini. I can use Bluetooth on the Android phones almost without problems by using native extensions, but I am a bit confused about how to access it on the Mac Mini.

Any research about native extension leads me to mobile related links.

Any idea on how I could send and receive data to/from bluetooth on osX?
Is native extensions the way to go? And in case that was the way, do you know if there is any Native Extension available that I can use? Writing one on my own can be a bit overwhelming...

Comment: Regarding OS-X ANEs; be aware that Air 20 (in beta now), is now 64-bit based and thus your ANE needs to be a 64-bit dylib...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need a native extension to access Bluetooth on the Mac.

The process should be more or less the same as on mobile, except of course the Mac extension will need to be built to target OS X instead of Android. A quick Google search turned up this article which might help get you headed in the right direction:
[How to Create an Adobe AIR Native Extension for Mac OSX](http://www.riaxe.com/blog/how-to-create-an-adobe-air-native-extension-for-mac-osx/)

Comment: Thx @Cadin, unfortunately writing on my own the Native Extension can be a bit challenging... Are you aware if there is anything ready made? :)

Comment: I don't know about that, sorry. You can try searching around for something, but my guess is you'll need to write it yourself or hire someone to create it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Library [FPBluetooth.ane](http://flashpress.ru/blog/ane/bluetooth/?lang=en) supported platforms iOS+OSX.